# IFNULL equivalent in Hibernate Query Language?

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to write an HQL query which will calculate an average rating for an item. I want the query to return 0 instead of null when there are no rating for a given item - so that I can use my query as a subquery. So is it possible? Is there an HQL equivalent of IFNULL or NVL?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**COALESCE** is the official equivalent.

It returns the first non-null of its arguments.

Example:

```
    COALESCE(id_pati, 0)
```

Link [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#COALESCE)

Answer (score 3):

Nhibernate docs are out of date.
Check http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

If nothing works you can try:

```
select 
   case 
     when something is not NULL then 0
     else 
   end
```