# How to use syntax of mysql such as ifnull(max(Id),0) in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

look likes Hibernate have not this syntax,that is right?[image]

```
public int MaxIdenx() {
    int max = 0;
    String hql = "select ifnull(max(empId),0)from Emp";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    List currentSeq = query.list();
    if (currentSeq == null) {
        return max;
    } else {
        max = (Integer) currentSeq.get(0);
        return max + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error do you got? Post it please.

Comment: Btw, your function doesn't make much sense - DB should maintain sequences itself, not your application.

Comment: empId can be null. when my Emp table have values I can use this hql"select max(empId)from Emp". but when i use this hql if my database have no valus it also occur nullpoint exception so

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few problems with this....

- `IFNULL` is `COALESCE` in HQL ([IFNULL equivalent in Hibernate Query Language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657637/ifnull-equivalent-in-hibernate-query-language).)
- If you only want a single object back, use uniqueResult() instead of `list().get(0)`.
- HQL doesn't have every language construct that MySQL does. It might be better to use raw SQL, with `session.createSqlQuery()`.
- As zerkms says, it looks like you're managing your own sequences. Take a look at `IdentifierGenerator` (http://blog.anorakgirl.co.uk/2009/01/custom-hibernate-sequence-generator-for-id-field/).

Regardless though, the code would be...

```
public int MaxIdenx() {
    int max = (Integer)session
        .createQuery("SELECT COALESCE(MAX(empId), 0) FROM Emp")
        .uniqueResult();

    return max + 1;
}
```